# Deserialzing JSON with multiple types for a property

Tags: java, json, jackson, retrofit

I am working with a 3rd party API that returns three different types for the same JSON property, depending one how many nested objects it contains. I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle deserializing these objects using Jackson (preferably with Retrofit).

A simplified example: when retrieving a Customer record from this API, the response might be any one of:

1. Customer has multiple phone numbers; returns an array of `PhoneObjects`

   ```
   {
       "Phones": {
           "PhoneObject":[
               {"number":"800 555 6666","type":"Home"},
               {"number":"800 555 4444","type":"Work"}
           ]
       }
   }
   ```
2. Customer has one phone number; return a single `PhoneObject`

   ```
   {
       "Phones": {
           "PhoneObject": {"number":"800 555 6666","type":"Home"}
       },
   }
   ```
3. Customer has no phone numbers; return an empty string(!)

   ```
   {
       "Phones": {
           "PhoneObject":""
       }
   }
   ```

Currently, I handle this by deserializing with Jackson into a `Map<String, Object>` and inspecting the `Object` to determine what type it is, and then inserting it into, e.g. a `List<PhoneObject>` (returning an empty List if the object is not present). However this is cumbersome and would like to find a cleaner way to deserialize these objects.

Comment: Can you ask them to fix their API to return a sane response?

Comment: I agree that would be the best solution. Unfortunately that's not an option in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to parse all 3 JSON strings into this `Phones` class

```
class Phones {
    @JsonProperty("PhoneObject")
    private List<PhoneObject> phoneObjects;
}
```

with this `ObjectMapper` configuration:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
```

[ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) allows parsing a value into a list with size 1.

[ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT) allows parsing an empty string as a null. In this case `phoneObjects` ends up being `null`. Not ideal but I don't know of an easy way to get an empty list here.

You may or may not need [UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE) depending on your POJOs.

Comment: Thank you. Not only did this work like a charm, but I learned a lot more about Jackson.

Comment: How to do this if Im using a gsonBuilder to parse data?(                Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ProductModel>>() {
                }.getType();



                GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                
                ArrayList<ProductModel> products = gsonBuilder.create().fromJson(response, type);

)