# Modelling json data with unsure element

Tags: java, android, json, model

[image]

Suppose I have a json response(see image) with an element "meta_data". Now the peculiar thing about this meta_data list is that it may or may not exist, depending   upon if it has child elements. Not just this if it has only one child element then it will be shown as an object (key-value), instead of a list. So how can I model this element in my model Class, so that my app does not crash with errors like "Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 4864 path $[0].meta_data[0].value". Below is snipppet of my model class:

```
public class ProductModel {

    private List<MetaDatum> meta_data = null;


    public List<MetaDatum> getMetaData() {
        return meta_data;
    }

    public void setMetaData(List<MetaDatum> meta_data) {
        this.meta_data = meta_data;
    }

          // further more elements

    }
```

Comment: You have to check if(jsonRespons.has("meta_data")){// parse meta data }else{//catch your error}

Comment: where shall i check this condtion, in model class

Comment: Possible solution is: [eserialzing-json-with-multiple-types-for-a-property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527192/deserialzing-json-with-multiple-types-for-a-property)

Comment: When you parse data in Java class, use this condition.

Comment: you can use private "Object meta_data = null;" instead of private "List<MetaDatum> meta_data = null;" and cast it using "instanceOf" keyword either into the List or Object based on the response.

Comment: @Mayur thats a pretty good workaround. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code

```
 public class ProductModel {

        private Object meta_data = null;
        ...
    }
```

And cast it based on the response you received using **instanceof** keyword, Like

```
if(response instanceof List){
   //iterate list.
}
if(response instanceof Object){
  //use object.
}
```